# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [B

Tags: java, imagej

I tried to read an image from loci tools and save it to FileSaver from imagej
but, I got this error when running it

```
ImagePlus[] imps = BF.openImagePlus("path/to/my/file");
for (ImagePlus imp : imps)new FileSaver(imp).saveAsRaw("E:/test.raw");
```

when I run the code, it shows

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [B
at ij.io.ImageWriter.write(ImageWriter.java:272)
at ij.io.FileSaver.saveAsRaw(FileSaver.java:494)
at Skripsi.dcmtoraw.main(dcmtoraw.java:16)
```

Comment: Did you run though a debugger? Step into the methods and find out what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug, although it's not trivial to say whether the bug is in ImageJ 1.x, or in the Bio-Formats plugins.

[In the ImageJ 1.x code](https://github.com/imagej/ImageJA/blob/v1.50e/src/main/java/ij/io/ImageWriter.java#L269-L272), the `ImageWriter` assumes (unchecked) that the pixels array is an `Object[]` when the image is a stack, and a `byte[]` when it's a single image plane. However, it seems that Bio-Formats produces `ImagePlus` objects whose pixels are `Object[]` even for single planes. (Is your image a single plane?)

You could probably work around the issue by using the [Bio-Formats Exporter](http://imagej.net/Bio-Formats#Bio-Formats_Exporter) plugin to save your data.

Or you could use the [ImageJ2](http://imagej.net/ImageJ2) API, which will use [SCIFIO](http://imagej.net/SCIFIO) under the hood:

```java
/**
 * Adapted from the
 * <a href="https://github.com/imagej/imagej-tutorials">ImageJ Tutorials</a>
 * {@code LoadAndDisplayDataset} tutorial.
 */
@Plugin(type = Command.class, menuPath = "Plugins>My Useful Command")
public class UsefulCommand implements Command {

  @Parameter
  private DatasetIOService datasetIOService;

  @Parameter
  private LogService log;

  @Parameter
  private File destination;

  @Parameter
  private Dataset image;

  @Override
  public void run() {
    try {
      image = datasetIOService.save(image, destination.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    catch (final IOException exc) {
      log.error(exc);
    }
  }

}
```